# 2 QMainWindow glued - Size of Layout

Tags: qt, qwidget, qmainwindow

I have a main window that I center this way in main.cpp :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QMainWindow *qmain = new QMainWindow;
     Ui_MainWindow ui;
     ui.setupUi(qmain);
     QRect r = qmain->geometry();
     r.moveCenter(QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry().center());
     qmain->setGeometry(r); 
     qmain->show();
     return app.exec();
}
```

In this "qmain" main window, I can create another QMainWindow and I try to make stick (or glue I don't know how to say) the two windows. Actually, I would like the right-top corner of the first one to be located at the left-top of the second one. For this, I use the following Ui_MainWindow's member function :

```
void Ui_MainWindow::generate_IC()
{
qmenu = new QMainWindow;
DiskMenu = new Ui_DiskGalMenu;
DiskMenu->setupUi(qmenu);
setInitialDiskMenuPosition(qmenu, this);
qmenu->show();
}
```

and the setInitialDiskMenuPosition :

```
void Ui_MainWindow::setInitialDiskMenuPosition(QMainWindow *MainWindow, Ui_MainWindow *parent)
{
        QSize size = parent->widget->size();
        QDesktopWidget* desktop = QApplication::desktop();
        int width = desktop->width();
        int height = desktop->height();
        int mw = size.width();
        int mh = size.height();
        int right = (width/2) + (mw/2);
        int top = (height/2) - (mh/2);
       MainWindow->move(right, top);
}
```

But the problem is that I don't get exactly what I want since the centralwidget size "parent-> widget->size()" only returns the size of the widget and not the whole "qmain" parent window. So I have a light shift because the borders of the "qmain" window are not taken in account like it is shown below :

[image]

If I could have access to the size of the whole parent window...

If anyone could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation you need to use parent->widget->frameGeometry().size() instead of parent->widget->size()

Comment: Even with parent->widget->frameGeometry().size(), this does not work. I am on Debian Squeeze GNU/Linux.

Comment: From documentation: "X11 provides no standard or easy way to get the frame geometry once the window is decorated. Qt solves this problem with nifty heuristics and clever code that works on a wide range of window managers that exist today. Don't be surprised if you find one where QWidget::frameGeometry() returns wrong results though."